# Trying to display only duplicate values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to display only the duplicate value in an array which just holds names.

So for instance, my code is:

```
  <%= s= arrayOfStuff %> 
  <%= t= arrayOfStuff.uniq %>
```

which displays

```
["UK01USV005", "NJ08APP516", "NJ08MHF001", "UK01USV505", "NY01MHF0006", "UK01USV525", "UK01USV005", "NJ08APP515", "NJ08MHF002"]
["UK01USV005", "NJ08APP516", "NJ08MHF001", "UK01USV505", "NY01MHF0006", "UK01USV525", "NJ08APP515", "NJ08MHF002"]
```

so theortically when I do `s-t` it should give me the duplicate value which in this case is `UK01USV005`, however the results I get is an empty array which obviously looks like this: `[]`.

Any ideas why that could be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
arrayOfStuff.group_by {|e| e}.select { |k,v| v.size > 1}.keys
```

should work fine.

Comment: By the way, only found out about group_by today, so that will be a great help for future references ;-)

Comment: There are a lot of nice features in ActiveSupport for Ruby Core. See https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext :)

Comment: By the way, been playing with the code now, but I can't seem to convert it into a String as I'm trying to do a comparison. Basically, I have the arrayOfStuff which are servers and each server is linked to an application. Some servers have more than 1 application, however I don't want to display two different outputs of the same server, but concatenate it under the same server. Hence I need to be able to compare the duplicate with the array by iterating through arrayOfStuff. Doe that make sense or is there a better way?

Comment: This is very nice. kudos!

Answer (score 5):

You're wrong.

```
["a", "a", "a"] - ["a"]
#=> []
```

You can try this in your case:

```
a.inject([]){|ar, item| b.include?(item) ? b.delete(item) : ar << item; ar}
#=> ["UK01USV005"]
```

or with your original Array

```
arrayOfStuff.select{|item| arrayOfStuff.count(item) > 1}.uniq
```

Comment: I prefer your last solution more than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting an array from an array removes *all* the matching objects, not only the first one.

See the simple test:

```
[1,2,1] - [1] # => [2]
```

So, if you want to scan for duplicate values, you may try `group_by` (as lucapette managed to suggest much faster) ;-)

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
["UK01USV005", "NJ08APP516", "NJ08MHF001", "UK01USV505", "NY01MHF0006", "UK01USV525", "NJ08APP515", "NJ08MHF002"] && ["UK01USV005", "NJ08APP516", "NJ08MHF001", "UK01USV505", "NY01MHF0006", "UK01USV525", "UK01USV005", "NJ08APP515", "NJ08MHF002"]

=> ["UK01USV005", "NJ08APP516", "NJ08MHF001", "UK01USV505", "NY01MHF0006", "UK01USV525", "UK01USV005", "NJ08APP515", "NJ08MHF002"]
```

Which is what you are looking for?